# What is the function of the ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.targets file?

Tags: arcobjects, add-in, arcgis-10.3

I am currently upgrading from 10.2 to 10.3 and as expected there are always some issues with recompiling addins and upgrading the the visual studio version.

There is now a known issue for which there is a workaround described [**here**](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/118989).

My question is **what is the function of the ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.targets file**?  What does it do and why does renaming the new ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.11.targets to the former ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.targets work?  Is it what packages the actual dll for use with ArcGIS applications?

Comment: for the cache? ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.SDK.dll needs to be added to assembly cache using gacutil.exe according to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114522/how-to-compile-an-arcgis-desktop-add-in-in-visual-studio-2013

Comment: Fixed the link.  I am just curious about what the .targets file is needed for, although I am guessing it has something to do with "packaging" the compiled dll into an esri addin.

Answer (score 1):

I have not familiar with this process but from reviewing a help page entitled [ESRI ArcGIS Add-In Installation Utility](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000009tm000000) that says things like:

> if the add-in specifies its target as 10.0

and

> An add-in targeting 10.1

and

> Add-ins can target only one version of ArcGIS. Add-ins targeting 10.0,
>   for example, will not show up in any other version.

I am going to take a guess that the targets file may contain the version number that an Add-in is targeting.