# Arc Map Addin creation problem with Visual Studio 2015 and ArcGIS 10.5.1

Tags: arcobjects, add-in

I am working with ArcMap Addins(Visual studio 2015 and ArcGIS 10.5.1 and OS Windows 7). code compiling time I got a error. same code I have used In Visual studio 2012 and Arc GIS 10.2 it is creation Addin with out any error.

I have changed my ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.targets file name to ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.11.targets. still my problem not solved.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The "ValidateAddInXMLTask" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. File name:
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'    at
>   ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.SDK.MSBuild.ValidateAddInXMLTask.Execute()    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]. TaxParcel_Attribution_Update

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to install the visual studio 2012 shell or copy its .dll into the GAC. [How to compile an ArcGIS Desktop add-in in Visual Studio 2013](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114522/how-to-compile-an-arcgis-desktop-add-in-in-visual-studio-2013)

Second of all The integer 11 was added for Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2013, and *removed at version 2015*. http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013261